# How can i display value binded from property to bootstrap date picker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, bootstrap-datetimepicker

js code

```
$('.date ').each(function () {
    $(this).datepicker("clearDates");
});
```

My model Property

```
[Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
public Nullable<DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { @class = "form-control date" } )
```

I already tried adding some formatting but still displaying birthdate retrieved from the db doesn't work.

EDIT EDIT! this line was responsible for that.

```
$(this).datepicker("clearDates");
```

Follow up question.

How can I make it to display mm/dd/yy format?

This is the value displayed in input type
     11/3/2015 12:00:00 AM

EDIT AGAIN! new code for js, this solved my latter problem.

```
$('.date ').each(function () {
    $(this).datepicker("update", new Date());
});
```